# Can I check the contents of encrypted archive without using password?

Tags: encryption, archive, zip

I need to **create and encrypt archive** with some files. Later **archive contents must be checked** by someone who **doesn't know encryption password**.

I've done my research but couldn't find proper tool for this job. The easiest way to encrypt archive is *zip --encrypt* but I'am not sure I would have an opportunity to look inside it without using password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with Zip files, since here the contents of each contained file is encrypted, but the Zip file itself is not.

Install Zip on Ubuntu: (not installed by default)

```
sudo apt install zip
```

Create a password protected archive: (compress all files recursively inside `directory`)

```
zip -r -P password myfile.zip ./directory/
```

View all files inside: (without being prompted for password)

```
zip -sf myfile.zip    # Only filenames

unzip -l myfile.zip   # Size, date and filenames
```

And to unzip the archive: (you'll be prompted for password at first file)

```
unzip myfile.zip
```

Comment: Thank you for help! But zip -sf shows me only top directory. Can I somehow recursively view all files inside directory?

Comment: For me (on Ubuntu 22.04), `zip -sf` as well as `unzip -l` shows all files recursively.

Comment: My bad, everything works correctly!